# Specific number of equilibrium points for a family of DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Give an example of a family of differential equations $x'=f_a(x)$ for which there are no equilibrium points if $a<0$; a single equilibrium point if $a=0$ and 4 equilibrium points if $a>0$.

Note: The number of equilibria it's for differing values of a.

I solved a similar  exercise of differential equations but it only has a single equilibrium point if $a=1/4$,2 equilibrium points if $a<1/4$ and 0 equilibrium points if $a>1/4$.

$x'=x^2+y, y'=x-y+a$,

The example above can help to solve the first exercise? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\dot x&=&x^2-a\\
\dot y&=&y^2-a\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
has no equilibrium points if $a<0$, one equilibrium point $(0,0)$ if $a=0$ and 4 equilibrium points $(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{a})$, $(-\sqrt{a},\sqrt{a})$, $(\sqrt{a},-\sqrt{a})$, $(-\sqrt{a},-\sqrt{a})$ when $a>0$.